# Can I customize Json.NET serialization without annotating my classes?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, json.net

I need to serialize some entity classes to JSON, using Json.NET. In order to customize the names of the properties, I use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute like this:

```
    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

The problem is, I'd prefer not to have any JSON-related attributes in my entities... Is there a way to externalize the annotations somehow, so that they don't clutter my entities?

Using `XmlSerializer`, it can be done easily with the [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) class. Is there something similar for Json.NET ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom contract resolver and customize the `JsonProperty` definition without the use of attributes. Example follows:

```
class Person { public string First { get; set; } }

class PersonContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(
        MemberInfo member, 
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(Person) && member.Name == "First")
        {
            property.PropertyName = "FirstName";
        }

        return property;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            new Person { First = "John" },
            new JsonSerializerSettings 
            { 
                ContractResolver = new PersonContractResolver() 
            });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

This output of this sample program will be the following:

```
// {"FirstName":"John"}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good solution. I will probably try to make it more generic though...

Comment: I eventually took a different route (I created specific classes instead of serializing the entities directly to JSON), but I'll keep your solution in mind for next time. Thanks!