# Use JsonIgnore on certain inherited properties

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, jsonresult

I have a base class like this-ish:

```
public class Baseclass
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...and many classes that inherit these properties, like this-ish:

```
   public class Thing: Baseclass
    {
     public string Size{ get; set; }
     public string Color{ get; set; }
     public string Smell{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I don't want to serialize all of these properties (mvc/jsonresult), so I use [JsonIgnore] on the properties of a class I want to exclude, and that works fine.  The problem is that I don't want to serialize all the inherited properties for a class either. I've asked around and gotten the following answer:

Ex: I don't want to serialize the inherited Id from Baseclass in Thing.

I should make Id in Baseclass virutal:

```
public virtual string Id { get; set; }
```

and add the following to the Thing class:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public override string Id { get; set; }
```

...but this doesn't work, I'm afraid. I can get around it rebuilding the class hierarchy. but I would prefer a simpler solution. Any suggestions as to why this solution didn't work or alternatives to exclude certain inherited properties?

Comment: Why do you not want to serialize it?  If the derived class does not need that property then it sounds like it shouldn't be in your base class.

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638778/avoid-using-the-jsonignore-attribute-in-a-domain-model) workaround

Comment: When I apply the [JsonIgnore] attribute to the "Id" property it does not serialize or de-serialize. I must be missing something: `var x = new Thing() { Id = "1", Type = "2", Name = "3", Size = "4", Color = "5", Smell = "6" };
            var y = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
            var z = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(y);`

Comment: Some suggestions here: [Ignore Base Class Properties in Json.NET Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104335/ignore-base-class-properties-in-json-net-serialization).  `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` looks like the easiest solution.  In fact, is this a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Some of the solutions are pretty close, but after some discussion with my co-worker, we have decided to rewrite the classes to avoid redundant properties instead, less messy.